# Xamarin.Forms UWP UI Testing

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms, ui-testing

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and UWP and I am looking for more information on UI testing Xamarin.Forms UWP projects.

Can anyone provide more info about ways to UI test Xamarin.Forms UWP projects?

Comment: Does any body has any views on this area? I am also looking for the same solution. Any suggestion or direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Guess you'll need to use something like http://appium.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a great frameworke called Windows Application Driver. It's super simple to to get running. You just install, and then run the samples. There are some samples of in built Windows apps like Calculator which show you how to get going straight away.

https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver

Just clone the repo and off you go.

*Note: to test on Android and iOS, you can use https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/uitest-and-test-cloud/ which I guess is not compatible with Windows Application Driver. But, between the two frameworks, you can cover all three platforms.*